# (Qt) two rows of widgets in a toolbar

Tags: qt, pyqt, toolbar

I can't figure out how creating a toolbar with two rows of widgets. I'm working on a Python3/Qt4 project.

My guess :

- add a widget to the toolbar widget
- add a vertical layout (or a QGridLayout, it doesn't matter) to the widget
- add the toolbar's buttons to the layout

But all I get is a tiny and empty toolbar : do I need to somehow 'stretch' the widget ?

My Python3 code, trying to insert vertically two buttons in the toolbar :

```
    self.main_toolbar = self.addToolBar('MyToolBar')

    self.toolbar_widget = QtGui.QWidget(self.main_toolbar)
    self.toolbar_layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
    self.toolbar_widget.setLayout(self.toolbar_layout)

    button1 = QtGui.QPushButton(self)
    button1.setText("button1")
    self.toolbar_layout.addWidget( button1 )

    button2 = QtGui.QPushButton(self)
    button2.setText("button2")
    self.toolbar_layout.addWidget( button2 )
```

Comment: Why are you adding the buttons to layout and not the toolbar widget?Try adding the buttons to the toolbar_widget.addWidget(button1)

Comment: You can't add a widget to a widget : Attribute Error : 'QWidget' object has no attribute 'addWidget' .

Comment: QToolbar has a method      QAction * QToolBar::addWidget ( QWidget * widget )

Comment: Exact : but toolbar.addWidget(button1) doesn't take in account the vertical layout. Or I am missing something ?

Comment: I am a C++ and QT user but still the concept of layout and widget are same ,so you can have a layout(vertical or horizontal) to this layout you will add ONLY your toolbar Widget .But in your toolbar widget you will add all the required buttons and after adding all the buttons in your toolbar widget ,you will just call layout->addWidget(QToolBar*).Hope it clarifies

Comment: I don't understand the last part of your explanations : in "layout->addWidget(QToolBar*)" what's the "layout" you're talking about ?

Comment: Ok you can forgot that ,instead you are using SetLayout.So just add widgets(button) to your toolbar.

Answer (score 1):

It's simple: you really need two toolbars, one under another.

You can't merely add child widgets to a toolbar. Your `main_toolbar` is presumably of the `QToolBar` class. You can't simply add a `toolbar_widget` to it!

Neither you can change the layout of a `QToolBar`. The toolbar manages the layout of its children itself, you're not supposed to mess with it - it's not designed that way.

The only way of adding widgets to a toolbar is via the `addWidget` method *of the toolbar*, **not of the layout!**

Your code is wrong. What you can do, and all that you can do with a toolbar is:

```
self.main_toolbar = self.addToolBar('MyToolBar')

button1 = QtGui.QPushButton(self)
button1.setText("button1")
self.main_toolbar.addWidget( button1 )

button2 = QtGui.QPushButton(self)
button2.setText("button2")
self.main_toolbar.addWidget( button2 )
```

What you want to do is simply not supported by the toolbar. The toolbar may, perhaps, arrange its items in more than one row *if* they don't all fit. It probably depends on the style. You're free to insert "tall" toolbar widgets that have an internal layout and two sub-buttons inside, but it'll look very ugly.

Comment: This is all completely wrong :) You can add any widgets you like to a toolbar, just like any other container widget.

Comment: @ekhumoro I didn't say you can't add the widgets you like, just that you can't change the layout on a toolbar. A toolbar manages its own layout, so `self.toolbar_widget.setLayout(self.toolbar_layout)` is wrong.

Comment: It's not wrong at all! The code in the question works perfectly fine (it's easy enough to test for yourself if you won't believe me). The only thing missing is to explicitly add the widget to the toolbar.

Comment: @ekhumoro Generally, if you add a widget to the layout that's set on a widget, you don't need to add it to that widget as well. Alas, `QToolBar` it's not supposed to be used that way. Seriously. You're not supposed to set any layouts on it. You're supposed only to call `QToolBar::addAction` or `QToolBar::addWidget`. Yes, it "works" if you abuse it that way, but you're defeating toolbar's inherent functionality that way. Good luck with navigating those buttons, etc.

Comment: @ekhumoro Basically, there's no reason to use `QToolBar` if you want to manage the layout itself. Just use a `QWidget`. I mean - what's the point of a `QToolBar`, if not for the inherent layout of the widgets that it provides.

Comment: @ekhumoro: Well, main_toolbar is presumably of the QToolBar class, you can't add random child widgets to it!

Comment: I think calling the layout `toolbar_layout` is what may be confusing things here. It perhaps should have been called `toolbar_widget_layout`. All the layout is doing is managing the vertical arrangement of the two buttons within the widget, not the toolbar itself.

Comment: @ekhumoro He is not supposed to add that widget as a child widget to an instance of `QToolBar`. End of story. Right there.

Comment: The toolbar will take ownership of whatever widget is added to it using `addWidget`. It will wrap the widget in a `QWidgetAction` and reset the widget's parent in the process. Adding widgets to a toolbar in this way is quite common (e.g. a font-selector combo-box in a word-processing app).

Answer (score 1):

The code you posted is fine, it's just that you forgot to add your widget to the toolbar.

You can do this using [QToolBar.addWidget](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtoolbar.html#addWidget):

```
    self.main_toolbar.addWidget(self.toolbar_widget)
```

Comment: Of course it'll look like crap, and it's not how you're supposed to use a toolbar.

Comment: @KubaOber. It seems okay to me, especially if the layout margin is removed and the spacing is adjusted. Basically, it just looks like two narrow buttons, one above the other - which I suppose is what the OP was after.